# Why does FunctionTransformer pass check_inverse?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

How come the `check_inverse` parameter in `FunctionTransformer` does not throw an error?

In the `FunctionTransformer` [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer.html#sklearn.preprocessing.FunctionTransformer), the parameter `check_inverse` is defaulted to be True, and as far as I understand it, it checks that, for an array X, that f^-1(f(X))=X.

In the [example](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/preprocessing/plot_function_transformer.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-preprocessing-plot-function-transformer-py) given, it removes the first column of the array X. How come removing the first column, which is not an invertible operation, pass the test?

I was expecting there to be a warning that the condition is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this is sadly only provided if you read the code. If no inverse function is given, the check is not applied:

```
if (self.check_inverse and not (self.func is None or
                                        self.inverse_func is None)):
      self._check_inverse_transform(X)
```

from [FunctionTransformer](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/1495f69242646d239d89a5713982946b8ffcf9d9/sklearn/preprocessing/_function_transformer.py#L133).

Comment: If this is the condition, what case is there where the inverse function does exist and the check fails? Wouldn't the existence of the inverse function automatically mean that the transform works?

Comment: You need to provide the inverse function. So if you just check it for a very special case where it works and apply it to a more general case with the `FunctionTransformer` it may possible that the inverse transformation does not work for the more general case.